# How to calculate the density of $X^2+Y^2$ when $(X,Y)$ is uniform on a disc?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I am looking the following:

The pair of random variables $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on disc of radius $R$  and center $(0,0)$. Let $Z=X^2+Y^2$. I want to find the density $f_Z(t)$ for small $t$.

For that do we use that the intergral of density has to be equal to $1$ to calculate $f_z(t)$ ?

Or is tere an other way?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $Z \leq t$ iff $(X,Y)$ lies inside the circle of radius $\sqrt t$ centered at the origin.

$P(Z \leq t)=\frac {\pi t} {\pi R^{2}}$ since the area of the circle of radius $\sqrt t$ around the origin is $\pi t$. Hence $f_Z(t)=\frac 1 {R^{2}}$ for $0 <t < R^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The $\text{cdf}$ is such that

$$\text{cdf}_Z(t)=\mathbb P(Z\le t)=\mathbb P(X^2+Y^2\le t)=\frac{\pi t}{\pi R^2}$$

which is simply the ratio of the areas, as the distribution is uniform.

The $\text{pdf}$ follows by differentiation on $t$,

$$\text{pdf}_Z(t)=\frac{1}{R^2}.$$

Note that $t$ *small* means $0\le t\le R$. Elsewhere, the $\text{pdf}$ vanishes.